# How to load a preset list of Tasker profiles into another user's installation of Tasker

Tags: tasker

I'm new to both Android and Tasker. I have two Android devices, and have created a bunch of Tasker profiles/scenes/tasks on Device 1 and would like to have those same profiles/scenes/tasks on Device 2, but don't want to enter all of them in again. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's indeed a possibility:

Hit Menu (the three dots in the top right corner if you don't have hardware buttons) -> Data -> Backup. Then copy the Tasker folder on your SD-Card to the one of your second device. There, hit Menu -> Data -> Restore. That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Tasker has the ability to perform a backup and export. If not, find the directory in which the above are stored and copy them to the other phone?

Try reading this blog: http://almost-a-technocrat.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/how-to-export-taskers-projects-profiles.html?m=1